# jQuery drag-drop, clone and rotate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Im trying to get a div to first clone itself then drag and drop, that works but i need to let the user rotate it aswell.

look at the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/zduEZ/

```
// Your original element
var ele = $('.draggable');

$('.draggable').draggable({ helper: "clone" });
$('.draggable').bind('dragstop', function (event, ui) {
    $(this).after($(ui.helper).clone().draggable()); });

    // Create handle dynamically
    $('<div></div>').appendTo(ele).attr('id', 'handle').css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'bottom': 5,
        'right': 5,
        'height': 10,
        'width': 10,
        'background-color': 'green'
    });

    ele.css('position', 'relative');

    $('#handle').draggable({
        handle: '#handle',
        opacity: 0.01,
        helper: 'clone',
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            var rotateCSS = 'rotate(' + ui.position.left + 'deg)';
            $(this).parent().css({
                '-moz-transform': rotateCSS,
                '-webkit-transform': rotateCSS
            });
        }
    });
```

i want it to rotate like this example: http://jsfiddle.net/avPf6/1/

I cant find the error in my code.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not attaching the draggable to the new created elements so I build up a function `applyRotation` and call it on `dragstop` (I think this can be better), I add another check to avoid the cloning of the round selector when you rotate the "master" element:

```
if ($(ui.helper).hasClass('rotator'))
        return true
```

Finally I don't use any id, only classes, to avoid ID's conflict on cloning.

The final code looks like this:

```
// Your original element
var ele = $('.draggable');

$('.draggable').draggable({
    helper: "clone"
});
$('.draggable').bind('dragstop', function (event, ui) {
    if ($(ui.helper).hasClass('rotator'))
        return true
    $(this).after($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());
    applyRotation();
});

// Create handle dynamically
$('<div class="rotator"></div>').appendTo(ele).addClass('handler').css({
    'position': 'absolute',
        'bottom': 5,
        'right': 5,
        'height': 10,
        'width': 10,
        'background-color': 'green'
});

ele.css('position', 'relative');

applyRotation();

function applyRotation() {
    $('.handler').draggable({
        opacity: 0.01,
        helper: 'clone',
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            var rotateCSS = 'rotate(' + ui.position.left + 'deg)';

            $(this).parent().css({
                '-moz-transform': rotateCSS,
                    '-webkit-transform': rotateCSS
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zduEZ/11/